# Smooth scroll with Native Javascript inside a div

Tags: javascript

Assume the following:

```
<div class="container" style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
   <div style="height: 50px">item</div>
   <div style="height: 50px">item</div>
   <div style="height: 50px">item</div>
</div>
```

Now, I read this article https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/, which explains how it is possible to smooth-scroll with native javascript, but the method seems only available to the window object.

I was wondering if any of you good people know how to use this method on the container div in my code?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I thought it would be as easy as:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.scroll({
   top: 100, 
   left: 0, 
   behavior: 'smooth'
})
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox please see my edit

Comment: Try: `$('.container').scroll({ top: 100, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })`

Comment: @Guedes nothing to do with jquery in this question